# Optimized filesystem for low throughput devices

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi

I'm about to set up a gentoo partition on a very low throughput device (sd card) for a raspberry pi. Are there any filesystems optimized to run as a root partition with low throughput and storage space?

Comment: I am not up to date on modern GNU/Linux systems so I can not answer your question. However I am interested in getting my own raspberry pi and I looked at SDcards for it. One of the things I ran in to is the difference in access time with different SDcards. Toms hardware has a nice article on it which probably explains it a lot better than I can. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/sdxc-sdhc-uhs-i,2940-9.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quite new filesystem called [f2fs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS) optimized for high level access to NAND flash memory, such as SD cards. The outstanding feature of f2fs is reduced wearing, which is the big issue with flash memory. The wearing is especially bad with journaling filesystems, and filesystems mounted with atime enabled. The throughput and storage capacity are not at all bad, compared to floppy disks for example. Any common filesystem like ext2 deals very well with this.